# p = open(q,'r') FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'm.txt'

Tags: python

put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► *italic* or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

► backtick escapes `like _so_`

► quote by placing > at start of line

► to make links (use https whenever possible)
https://example.com

Comment: You must pass an argument to that script. It still won't work as `m` is not defined though. Also there is nothing in the code that uses the argument passed, so I'm not sure if you are posting the actual script or some hypothetical pseudo-code.

Comment: Why does the error in the headline differ from the one in the text and the code?

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv` is a list containing the program as invoked, and the arguments passed to it.

You've invoked the program as `python3 proj.py`, which means that `sys.argv == ['proj.py']`.

You then asked the program to access the second element of `sys.argv` via `sys.argv[1]`. There is no second element, so this **fails** with the given error.

Had you invoked the program as `python3 proj.py foo`, then `sys.argv == ['main.py', 'foo']` and `sys.argv[1] == 'foo'`.